# XmlSlurper namespaces not being used

Tags: xml, groovy

I have an XML template document:

```
<TriadMessage xmlns="http://www.myco.com/02/11/2008/V1/TriadMessage.xsd" 
        xmlns:triad="http://www.myco.com/02/11/2008/V1/TriadTypes.xsd" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
<TriadRouteInfo>
   <triad:RoutingCorrelationId>new value goes here</triad:RoutingCorrelationId>
...
```

that I read using Groovy 1.7:

```
triadDoc = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlMessage).declareNamespace(
    tm: "http://www.myco.com/02/11/2008/V1/TriadMessage.xsd", 
    triad: "http://www.myco.com/02/11/2008/V1/TriadTypes.xsd", 
    xsi: "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    )
xmlBuilder = new StreamingMarkupBuilder()
writer = xmlBuilder.bind {mkp.yield triadDoc}
```

I then insert values into the document:

```
triadDoc.TriadRouteInfo.RoutingCorrelationId = dto.getReportRevisionId()
...
```

and output:

```
writer.toString()
```

This is what my document looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <tm:TriadMessage xmlns:tm="http://www.myco.com/02/11/2008/V1/TriadMessage.xsd">
  <tm:TriadRouteInfo>
     <triad:RoutingCorrelationId xmlns:triad="http://www.myco.com/02/11/2008/V1/TriadTypes.xsd">24670</triad:RoutingCorrelationId>
...
```

Notice that the **triad** namespace appears with each element. There are a lot of these lines (I only show one here).  I want to have the NS declared at the top only and referred via **triad:** below.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried this:

```
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder

def xml = """
<TriadMessage xmlns="http://www.myco.com/02/11/2008/V1/TriadMessage.xsd" 
                           xmlns:triad="http://www.myco.com/02/11/2008/V1/TriadTypes.xsd" 
                           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
  <TriadRouteInfo>
    <triad:RoutingCorrelationId>new value goes here</triad:RoutingCorrelationId>
  </TriadRouteInfo>
</TriadMessage>"""


def triadDoc = new XmlSlurper().parseText( xml ).declareNamespace(
  tm:    "http://www.myco.com/02/11/2008/V1/TriadMessage.xsd", 
  triad: "http://www.myco.com/02/11/2008/V1/TriadTypes.xsd", 
  xsi:   "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" )

def xmlBuilder = new StreamingMarkupBuilder()
writer = xmlBuilder.bind {
  mkp.declareNamespace( tm:    "http://www.myco.com/02/11/2008/V1/TriadMessage.xsd" )
  mkp.declareNamespace( triad: "http://www.myco.com/02/11/2008/V1/TriadTypes.xsd" )
  mkp.declareNamespace( xsi:   "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" )
  mkp.yield triadDoc
}

triadDoc.TriadRouteInfo.RoutingCorrelationId = 'wheeee'

println writer
```

And it printed out this (prettied up by me, so it's not all on one line):

```
<tm:TriadMessage xmlns:tm='http://www.myco.com/02/11/2008/V1/TriadMessage.xsd'
                 xmlns:triad='http://www.myco.com/02/11/2008/V1/TriadTypes.xsd'
                 xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>
  <tm:TriadRouteInfo>
    <triad:RoutingCorrelationId>wheeee</triad:RoutingCorrelationId>
  </tm:TriadRouteInfo>
</tm:TriadMessage>
```

Any good?